# Flink Install on OSX can't find org.apache.hadoop.util.StringUtils

Tags: macos, apache-flink

According to the [Flink QuickStart page](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.3/quickstart/setup_quickstart.html), the install couldn't seem to be easier.

```
 $ brew install apache-flink
 ...
 $ flink --version
```

When I run the flink command, I get the following:

```
$ flink --version
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.hadoop.util.StringUtils
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.SecurityUtil.getAuthenticationMethod(SecurityUtil.java:611)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.initialize(UserGroupInformation.java:272)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.setConfiguration(UserGroupInformation.java:311)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.security.modules.HadoopModule.install(HadoopModule.java:49)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.security.SecurityUtils.install(SecurityUtils.java:78)
    at org.apache.flink.client.CliFrontend.main(CliFrontend.java:1128)
```

Not clear to me what I am missing from the QuickStart page!?

Comment: I just tried this, and it worked for me. That class is in /usr/local/Cellar/apache-flink/1.3.2/libexec/lib/flink-shaded-hadoop2-uber-1.3.2.jar. What version of Java are you using?

Comment: I am using ... Java 9. Think that might be it!?

Comment: Maybe. I don't think Java 9 is supported yet.

Comment: Could you share with us the contents of the client log file which you find under `FLINK_HOME/libexec/log`? This could give us information whether there are wrong dependencies in your classpath.